# During the transition period will UK membership contributions continue as before, in addition to the divorce bill?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit

During the transition period (assuming there is one) I understand UK membership contributions to the EU will continue as before. But will these be in addition to the £39 billion “divorce bill”?

Restated: is the £39 billion divorce bill value contingent on there being no deal/a deal?

Comment: Should answers assume that there will actually be a transition period? If the draft exit agreement is rejected (still very possible) or modified (as some seem to believe possible), then this could all change.

Comment: Duplicate of https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/35533/why-is-the-magnitude-of-the-uk-eu-divorce-bill-not-contingent-on-a-deal?

Answer (score 6):

The deal has not been agreed yet, but the current proposal is to keep paying during the transition period in addition to the £39 billion divorce bill. The bill will be paid out over a long period of time, decades in fact.

The £39 billion is not contingent on a deal. The UK already committed to paying it, in multiple legally binding agreements.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing, but here's a reference from March 2018: https://theconversation.com/brexit-transition-three-misunderstandings-about-the-deal-explained-93784

Comment: One thing to note is that the figure of £39 billion is still only an estimate. The UK government has vowed to honour its commitments, but what those commitments end up being is the result of an accounting process. Part of the draft exit is a summary of how the valuations will work. https://fullfact.org/europe/eu-divorce-bill/